# Different colors for questions and answers in org-mode

Tags: org-mode, syntax-highlighting, colors

I'm writing questions and answers in org-mode for project purposes (like meeting notes). A sample looks like this:

`1. [X] Equipment name for tags associated with pumps - Discuss 
   Comment: We can just use MP-516A/T. I’ve updated your ACM names as well
2. [X] Why have the steps D12516_DirectXfer and D12516_LnClr not included in the steps? Step enable conditions to be
   added 
   Comment: I bet the tool didn’t add the columns. If you manually added the columns to this tab, it will be perfectly
   fine. We can proceed with filling out the enable conditions for these columns.`

The screenshot shows how I see it on the screen

[image]

**Question:**

I would want at least one of them (either the answer or question) to be shown in a different color.  Is that possible? or am I asking for too much?

Comment: It would help if you clarified which part is the question and which part is the answer.  But if you stick to a consistent syntax, like prefix questions with `Q:` and answers with `A:`, or something like that, you could just use something like `highlight-regexp`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try using a [description list](http://orgmode.org/manual/Plain-lists.html) instead:

```
- Question :: Answer
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that Prasanna is right!  I used this bit of code to add italics to web-mode just now:

```
        (highlight-regexp "<em>\\([a-zA-Z0-9 ]+\\)</em>" 'web-mode-italic-face)
```

So now in web-mode, most characters between "<em>" and "</em>" will have an italic face.  Cool no?

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer. I guess web-mode and org-mode are two different modes

Answer (score 0):

Assume all questions start with "Q: ", then you can add this to your init.el to highlight all questions using comment color:

```
(font-lock-add-keywords
  'org-mode
  '(("\\( Q: .+\\)" (1 'font-lock-comment-face t))))
```